# Hibernate could not tell whether Object is proxy or real

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence

I got this `object` under control. On `object.getClass()` it says `com.mypack.class_james_007`, I consider this object is uninitialized till now and belongs to `class's` proxy.

I test `org.hibernate.Hibernate.isInitialized(object)`, it says true.

I do  `org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(object)`. After this on `object.getClass()` it still says `com.mypack.class_james_007`.

Shouldn't it get initialized the object on `initialize(o)` by returning normal class name on calling `getClass()`.
This behaviour confuses me, please help me guys. What's the catch there?

The reason I incurred this problem is while implementing equals methods of my domain.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy can be in two state: initialized or not. Initialization of proxy do not change it runtime type (nothing can do that), but just load data in underlying non-proxy object.

Comment: then how can one access that underlying actual object?

Comment: I use `session.load(id)` or something similar. But your newer need it actually :)

Comment: my newer? what does it mean?

Comment: You just use what Hibernate gave you and don't think about is it proxy or not, There are only several cases when real runtime class matter. And all of them caused by bed design :)